# Am I violating the SRP using inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, single-responsibility-principle

I am trying to understand the SRP(Single Responsibility Principle).Below is the sample code:

```
public interface IInventoryManager
{
    int GetInboundItemsCount();
    int GetOutboundItemsCount();
}

public class GoodInventoryManager : IInventoryManager
{
    public int GetInboundItemsCount()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public int GetOutboundItemsCount()
    {
        //Returns the actual count;
        return 5;
    }
}

public class BadInventoryManager : IInventoryManager
{
    public int GetInboundItemsCount()
    {
        return 50;
    }

    public int GetOutboundItemsCount()
    {
        //Manipulates the actual count
        //And returns an incorrect count;
        //Actual number of items sold = 25, but he subtracts 5 and returns the count
        return 20;
    }
}

public interface ICalculate
{
    int Calculate();
}

public class ShopKeeper : ICalculate
{
    private readonly GoodInventoryManager _inventoryManager;
    public ShopKeeper(GoodInventoryManager inventoryManager)
    {
        _inventoryManager = inventoryManager;
    }
    public int Calculate()
    {
        return _inventoryManager.GetInboundItemsCount() - _inventoryManager.GetOutboundItemsCount();
    }
}

public class BigShopKeeper : ICalculate
{
    private readonly BadInventoryManager _inventoryManager;

    public BigShopKeeper(BadInventoryManager inventoryManager)
    {
        _inventoryManager = inventoryManager;
    }

    public int Calculate()
    {
        return _inventoryManager.GetInboundItemsCount() - _inventoryManager.GetOutboundItemsCount();
    }
}
```

//Obviously, the above code can be refactored to as below.`

```
public class ShopKeeper : ICalculate
{
    protected readonly IInventoryManager _inventoryManager;
    public ShopKeeper(IInventoryManager inventoryManager)
    {
        _inventoryManager = inventoryManager;
    }
    public int Calculate()
    {
        return _inventoryManager.GetInboundItemsCount() - _inventoryManager.GetOutboundItemsCount();
    }
}

public class BigShopKeeper : ShopKeeper
{
    public BigShopKeeper(IInventoryManager inventoryManager)
        :base(inventoryManager)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, somehow ShopKeeper wants to avoid paying taxes. So, he wants to modify the Calculate() method by showing that he is selling less. But instead of instructing his InventoryManager, he does it himself. This would result in modification in Calculate() method in ShopKeeper class. Now, Calculate() method for BigShopKeeper gets affected, which should not.

To achieve this, Calculate() method for ShopKeeper is made virtual. And the same method in BigShopKeeper class is overridden as follows:

```
public class ShopKeeper : ICalculate
{
    ...Code removed for brevity
    public virtual int Calculate()
    {
        var value = _inventoryManager.GetInboundItemsCount() - _inventoryManager.GetOutboundItemsCount();
        return value - 5;
    }
}

public class BigShopKeeper : ShopKeeper
{
    ...Code removed for brevity
    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return _inventoryManager.GetInboundItemsCount() - _inventoryManager.GetOutboundItemsCount();
    }
}
```

The Question is: A change in Calculate() method in ShopKeeper class forced an addition of Caculate() method in BigShopKeeper class. In other words, a change in one class forced a change in another class. Will this be called a Violation of SRP(Single Responsibility Principle)?

Thanks..

Comment: No takers on this.?

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously this is bad code, but you know that already.  You're telling the base class to do something which is unintuitive and its child would be expecting it to do the logical and intuitive thing.

Therfore `ShopKeeper` doesn't make sense as an extendable base class.  It's performing the expected calculation *and something else*. Based on these snippets alone it makes more sense for `ShopKeeper` to extend `BigShopKeeper` rather than the other way around.

Let's think about what the single responsibility is for each class and interface:

- `IInventoryManager`: responsible for accessing item counts.
- `GoodInventoryManager`/`BadInventoryManager`: same as above.
- `ICalculate`: responsible for returning the result of a calculation.  The interface doesn't tell us what that calculation represents.
- `ShopKeeper`: responsible for calculating an inventory count.
- `BigShopKeeper`: no responsibility of its own, based on the code you've posted.

I would move the calculation to `IInventoryManager`.  Make it have some method like `GetSubtractedItemsCount`.  I think this is still fitting with its purpose of "responsible for accessing item counts".

Different inventory managers could implement that method differently, if they want to mess with it.

Now the two types of `ShopKeeper` are just two instances of the same class which have different inventory manager properties.  But this class needs a new purpose because we've taken away its reponsibility.